# Add scatterplot on map with deck.gl

Tags: javascript, deck.gl

I am trying to make a map that shows a point which is located in Tokyo by defining longitude and latitude.
There is a map showed appropriately but not a point that should be there in red color. Hope someone can kindly find the reason why the point is not shown.

Below is my project repository's structure and codes.

```
-deck.gl
  index.html
  package-lock.json
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
 -dist
  bundle.js
  bundle.js.LICENSE.txt
  bundle.js.map
 -node_modules
 -src
  index.js


import { Deck } from 'deck.gl';
import { ScatterplotLayer } from '@deck.gl/layers';
import { MapboxLayer } from '@deck.gl/mapbox';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
  longitude: 139.6917,  
  latitude: 35.6895,   
  zoom: 10,
  pitch: 0,
  bearing: 0
};

const scatterplotLayer = new ScatterplotLayer({
  id: 'scatterplot-layer',
  data: [
    { position: [139.6917, 35.6895], size: 500 }  
  ],
  getRadius: d => d.size,
  getFillColor: [255, 0, 0, 180],  
  getPosition: d => d.position
});

const token = "MY-TOKEN"

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'app',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  accessToken: token,
  center: [INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.longitude, INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.latitude],
  zoom: INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.zoom
});

map.on('load', () => {
  const deckInstance = new Deck({
    mapboxApiAccessToken: token,
    initialViewState: INITIAL_VIEW_STATE,
    controller: true,
    layers: [scatterplotLayer],
    onWebGLInitialized: (gl) => {
      console.log('WebGL Initialized:', gl);
    }
  });

  map.addLayer(new MapboxLayer({ id: 'scatterplot-layer', deck: deckInstance }));
});



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.5.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>deck.gl Tutorial</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        #app { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```